# Why are string in .net case sensitive by default?

Tags: .net, string, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

Most times I want to do string comparisons I want them to be case insensitive.

So why are string in .net case sensitive by default?

**EDIT 1:** To be clear I think the below should return true by default. Or at least allow me to have a compile time flag that makes it so.

```
"John Smith" == "JOHN SMITH"
```

**EDIT 2:** I can think of many more examples of things that should be case insensitive

Examples of things that should be case insensitive

- Usernames
- Urls
- File extensions / File names / Directory names / Paths
- Machine / servernames
- State / Country / Location etc
- FirstName / LastName / Initials
- Guids
- Month / Day names

Examples of things that should be case sensitive

- Passwords

Comment: @bryan. you are correct that this is in my experience. although comparing to money is not really accurate

Comment: +1 to close. It seems like you are more interesting in expressing your disagreement with the decision than starting an honest inquiry.

Comment: @Bryan: not really. I am presenting my reasoning for asking the question. What I am hoping to get out of it is a some definitive reason as to why the contrary decision was made. Perhaps this should be community wiki??

Comment: Simon: Think of it from the other side: case-sensitive comparison is complex enough already and [every feature starts out with −100 points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx) – there have to be very compelling reasons to add extra complexity by making it case-insensitive by default. Also you add unexpected behavior that way, such as `ß` comparing equally to `ss` which is not necessarily always intended.

Comment: URIs are not case-insensitive, only the domain and scheme part. GUIDs should probably be compared as GUIDs and not as strings, making that a moot point as well.

Comment: @Simon: saying that `"John Smith" == "JOHN SMITH"` *should* return true indicates your disagreement. Your willingness to use IL weaving to subvert the language decision indicates a disdain. These properties of a question tend to lead to subjective and argumentative answers. I understand you are asking about why the decision was made, but your approach is heavy with your opinion.

Comment: Disagree with you on the Username comparison, that case sensitivity adds security to the situation...

Comment: @tekiegreg: It adds more annoyance for users than security. At least in any real-world system I've seen so far. He is right that for users almost nothing should be focibly case-sensitive. But for a general-purpose programming language I guess that's a wrong way to go.

Comment: I would never argue that they should be case insensitive by default. However, I *really* think it would have been good to provide a better way to do case insensitive comparisons than using helper methods that make your code go off the screen or take up multiple lines. Another type altogether that represents a case insensitive string type would be great, or even just some syntactic sugar... perhaps overloading or creating some new operator for that purpose.

Comment: Granted... on the list of great features I'm sure this one is not high on the list so I understand why they haven't done it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the trivial answer, but that's just the way it is :)

At a basic level, strings are represented as a list of characters, where 'a' is different from 'A', so it's probably the easiest representation \ convention overall. In your case, it's probably fair to say that the majority of comparisons is case-insensitive, but I think the other side of the argument holds true at least as much and a convention has been adopted.

I'd imagine utilizing some helper methods \ classes would ease your pain somewhat.

Comment: So is your answer  "they didn't think about it" or "it is for performance reasons"?

Comment: @cristobalito I dont want helper methods. I want "John Smith" == "JOHN SMITH" to return true.

Comment: I'd imagine it's mainly a historical issue - it's the way it's always been done, and what people probably expect. I'd be pretty surprised if "abc" == "ABC" returned true out of the box. Also, as you allude, it's also more computationally expensive and further-more, I guess you probably start running into further issues when you start considering unicode.

Comment: @simon But John Smith is not equal to JOHN SMITH. Well not to the computer

Comment: @Simon - for out of the box of such a feature, I think you'll need to change languages. I can't think of one of the top of my head though (html?)

Comment: @cristobalito re change language... perhaps. I am thinking of using IL Weaving like this project http://code.google.com/p/virtuosity/

Comment: @Simon: Are you the same Simon as the Simon in that project?

Answer (score 3):

Because there are different kinds of insensitive matching and it is unclear which one you want. Here are the three most common modes:

```
StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase
StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
```

They have vastly different uses cases. You probably did not notice that much because you are dealing with ASCII day-to-day. Users in other regions see more differences.

Answer (score 1):

Because case insensitivity is not performant and because it works even when you intend it not to.

Vendors need to compete based on performance and for that reason the default option tends to be the one that performs best.  At best, case insensitivity requires folding both strings to a common case prior to comparing.  At worst, depending on locale, it requires a code path that can be twice as long.  If the vendor defaulted to the less performant version, competitors would pick the worst-case scenarios to benchmark against.

Since case sensitivity fails on certain searches you are forced to address this in your code.  It forces a conscious decision.  In contrast, case insensitivity works, even in cases where you don't want it to.  Rather than forcing you to make a decision it creates a scenario where you can overlook it to your detriment.  As a matter of choice architecture, vendors tend to pick the option that leads to fewer defects - in this case that's case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

String comparison in .Net is case-sensitive because strings (and individual characters) are inherently case-sensitive.

The character 'a' is stored internally with a different ASCII or Unicode value as 'A'. Saying that 'a' is the same as 'A' is not "correct".

This distinction becomes critical when comparing values in languages other than English, when using algorithms like hash tables, or when using many encryption/decryption algorithms.

My two cents: case sensitive compare is the default because it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET it's possible to set the "option compare" to text to work case-insensitively but I highly discourage it.  My favorite is just to use the string.toLower() method when I need to compare insensitively and read the lower case version of the text.

Why?  Because how else would you compare when case sensitivity matters as it would in some applications?

Comment: Why not use the in-built string.Compare(string, string, bool) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx)

Comment: "how else would you compare when case sensitivity matters as it would in some applications"  
using 
string.Equals(a, b, StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
instead of 
string.Equals(a, b, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

Comment: a.Equals(b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) should be better than doing a ToLower on the string.

Comment: Good points, didn't think of those.  But I was working on a hypothetical scenario with a case insensitive only language, let's just assume for a moment that there was no way to state or mandate case sensitivity, now what?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the behaviour of existing classes. `System.String` class which is defined in mscorelib/system.core overrides == and defines a cases sensitive equality.

All you can do is to add an extension method to the string and implement a case-insensitive:

```
public static class StringEqualityExtension
{
    public static bool StringEquals(this string value, string other)
    {
       return value.ToLower()==other.ToLower();
    } 
}

// usage
string myString = "Some112";
string other = "sOME112";

bool equal = myString.StringEquals(myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

your case is not necessarily the most common case, a very common case is to match words in a document against grammar conditions, in that case case sensitivity is an absolute must.

Note matching in a case in-sensitive fashion is trivially easy. In fact the equals method of a string has an overload specifically for specifying how to compare.

Answer (score 0):

### I know this is necroposting, but

I came here searching for a solution to the same problem. Now it is almost 5 years later... but I don't mind, as this is one of the first search results and I think it would be better to include correct information.

According [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/8t3khw5f.aspx) you simply need to add 1 line of code to your file:

```
Option Compare Text
```

If you add the above line to the beginning of your core you are telling the CLR to switch from default (`Option Compare Binary`) to the case-insensitive comparison.

I don't know if this can work in C#.